# How to keep javadoc visible after obfuscating the code using ProGuard?

Tags: java, proguard

I obfuscating my code using progured 4.7, and im keeping class A that have javadoc describing what the class do.

```
-keep public class com.mysite.ClassA {public *;}
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keepparameternames
```

In eclipse when i try to view the docs for this class, eclipse tells me that there's no attached java doc. 
is there a way to solve this?

Comment: hmm .. simply attach javaDoc to the class/library?

Comment: Do you mean in Eclipse? is it an automated way ? (FYI this is a lib that i want to distributed).

Comment: If you see the lib in the package explorer, right click, choose Properties and you'll find a "JavaDoc Location" page in the properties dialog.

Comment: @Jimmy have you find an answer to your problem? I'm facing the same problem right now with the proguard javadoc issue.

Comment: @AviLevinshtein Unfortunately not at that time and decided to publish without it included.

Comment: See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29251158/1503237).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep javadoc visible after obfuscating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216211/how-to-keep-javadoc-visible-after-obfuscating)

Comment: In case anyone wonders why the old question got closed as a duplicate, Meta has the [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/135744).