# Keep Javadoc when running proguard

Tags: java, android, proguard

I am working on a (Android) library that I want to distribute. When generating the archive (`aar` file), I run Proguard to obfuscate the source code.

It works fine, except that the Javadoc is removed from the resulting files (if I open a file from my library from the IDE for example). Is it possible to configure Proguard in order to keep the Javadoc?
My current configuration is the following: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#library (without the first 4 lines).

I found this similar question: [How to keep javadoc visible after obfuscating the code using ProGuard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269205/how-to-keep-javadoc-visible-after-obfuscating-the-code-using-proguard) but it does not tell if it is possible or not.

Comment: did you find an answer for your problem?
I'm facing with the same issue right now.

Comment: Sadly, no. I didn't find a solution for this...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29251158/1377145

Comment: In case anyone wonders why the old question got closed as a duplicate, Meta has the [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/135744).