# How to keep javadoc visible after obfuscating

Tags: android, proguard, javadoc

I built a nice Javadoc documentation for my project which is a **JAR file** for developers.

But after I run proguard in order to obfuscat my code all the Javadoc documentation are gone.

**I would like to keep javadoc on all my public methods in the jar.**
Does anyone know how keep Javadoc visible after obfuscating?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't keeping Javadoc defeat the purpose of obfuscation?

Comment: Just use a tool like [doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/) to generate the documentation before you obfuscate. Obfuscating the code and leaving in the documentation makes the obfuscation pointless.

Comment: @Voicu In most cases yes but not if you build for example a jar file and you want developers to understand your public methods directly from code.

Comment: @John I can do it directly from android studio before the obfuscation step, thats an easy one. but i would like to keep the javadoc explanations for all the public methods which aren't obfuscated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javadoc is extracted from *source files*. It is not possible to create javadoc from *class files*, neither clean nor obfuscated. ProGuard operates on the *class files* created from compiling your *source files*, and produces *obfuscated class files* from it. This is completely unrelated to javadoc creation.

The output of the Javadoc processor usually goes to a directory structure. Of course, you can zip that and give it the `.jar` extension to provide the javadoc as well. I’ve seen it often (i.e, on Apache Commons) to name your library JAR some `foo-bar-1.2.3.jar` and the zipped javadoc `foo-bar-1.2.3-javadoc.jar`.

It is a good idea to provide the javadoc separated from the binary, as the binary needs to be included in a program distribution that relies on it, whereas the javadoc is only interesting for the developer and would only increase the size of the program without any need if it was in the same JAR.

In the IDE, you need to assign the javadoc JAR to the library JAR. In Eclipse, this can be done from the *Properties* → *Java Build Path* dialogue. After having added the JAR file, expand the white arrow next to the entry you created, select *Javadoc location* and then *Edit…*. Eclipse understands reading *Javadoc from archive* directly and you don’t need to unzip it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)'s page:

> ProGuard is integrated into the Android build system, so you do not have to invoke it manually. ProGuard runs only when you build your application in release mode, so you do not have to deal with obfuscated code when you build your application in debug mode. Having ProGuard run is completely optional, but highly recommended.

So I am not sure why are you *running* Proguard. Just configure it in your project and leave the build system to obfuscate upon release build. Your source code remains untouched this way.

Comment: I'm runing proguard upon release becuse i don't want people to see all my implementations. I would like people to see only the public methods in my JAR. on this point progurd is working great in which all can see just the public methods which aren't been obfuscated. I would like to do the same to the javadoc public methods. do you know how? :)